# Remove 'More..' link from RSS feed

Tags: rss, feed

I believe this can probably be done with a filter, but haven't been able to find any info so far about it.

We are pulling the description node from our RSS feed into some external properties. The problem is that wordpress is adding a Read More link to the feed. We need it to disappear.

Here is what a description node currently looks like:

```
<description>
<![CDATA[
This is the article text......[.....]

 <a class="alignright" href="http://www.site.com/permalink">Read More &#8230;</a>
]]>
</description>
```

And what we want it to look like

```
<description>
<![CDATA[
This is the article text............]
]]>
</description>
```

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: Is your feed set to show full content or excerpts? Do you use `<!--more-->` tag in content?

Comment: The feed is set to show the full content, but we're using the description node and not the content node, as we want to only show a paragraph and then link to the full blog.

Comment: This seems inconsistent with native behavior. [`the_excerpt_rss()`](http://queryposts.com/function/the_excerpt_rss/) function that is used in descriptions should not produce read more link by default. Are you adding read more links to excerpts in some other place in site?

Comment: We do have more links elsewhere as well. This theme was developed by a third party agency and I'm not 100% clued in on what all they modified. I didn't realize that the more link wasn't standard in WP installs. I will look at the functions file to see how they have modified the excerpt functions and report back.

Comment: Read more links are common in WP for full content with `<!--more-->` split, however this specific situation (excerpt in feed) should not have it natively I think.

Comment: How to do it? Any solution? Which file should I edit if my feed link is example.com/feed